# Problema con estructuras anidadas

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde tengo que cargar datos de alumnos. Lo hago mediante funciones utilizando estructuras. Tengo un problema de sintaxis de cómo guardar un dato en una estructura anidada.

Probé a hacerlo así:

```
a[i].fe.dia;
```

Y me marca el siguiente error:

> request for member 'dia' in '((+(((unsigned int)i) * 144u)) + a)-   >alumnos::fe', which is of non-class type 'fecha[2]'

y tambien probé de esta forma:

```
a.fe[i].dia;
```

y cuando lo hago me marca el siguiente error:

> 'fe' has not been declared

Pero de ninguna de las dos formas me funciona. No se si es que lo estoy haciendo mal o me faltó alguna declaracion o algo para que funcione.

```
struct fecha
{ 
   int dia, mes, anio;
};

struct alumnos
{
   int legajo [10];
   char apnom [35];
   char direc [40];
   struct fecha fe [2];  /* fecha nacimiento y fecha ingreso institución */
   int edad;
};

void carga_alu (struct alumnos [ ], int *); 


int main()
{

struct alumnos alum[100];
int cantalum;

carga_alu(alum,&cantalum); 




system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}


void carga_alu (struct alumnos a[ ], int *c)
{
char rta='s';
int i=0,cont=0;
while (rta=='s')
   { printf("Ingrese el nombre y apellido del alumno \n");
     gets(a[i].apnom);
     printf("Ingrese el legajo del alumno \n");
     scanf("%d",&a[i].legajo);
     printf("Ingrese la direccion del alumno \n");
     gets(a[i].direc);
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: DIA \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe.dia);
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: MES \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe.mes);
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: ANIO \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe.anio);
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: DIA           \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe.dia);
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: MES  \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe.mes);
     printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: ANIO \n");
     scanf("%d", &a[i].fe.anio);
     cont=cont+1;
     i=i+1;
     printf("Desea cargar otro alumno? S o N");
     scanf("%c",rta);} }
```

Comment: En los `scanf` tienes que pasar la dirección de memoria del dato, por ejemplo: `scanf("%d",&a[i].legajo);`.

Comment: Y como hago para ingresar datos a estructuras anidadas?? porque probe de esas dos formas y no me funciona @PaperBirdMaster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varios errores:

```
while (rta='s')
```

Ahí estás haciendo una asignación en vez de una comparación, luego tu código no va a abandonar nunca el bucle. La instrucción debería quedar así:

```
while (rta=='s')
```

Y con el tema de los índices, `a.fe[i]` comentarte lo siguiente:

- `a` es un arreglo, y el índice `i` debe actuar sobre `a`, al igual que sucede con `a[i].legajo`.
- `fe` es otro arreglo con dos elementos: `fe[0]` para la fecha de nacimiento y `fe[1]` para la fecha de ingreso.

Así pues para acceder al día de la fecha de nacimiento tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
a[i].fe[0].dia
```

Comentarte también que `scanf` requiere que las variables se las pases como punteros para poder modificar sus valores, luego el código tendría que quedar así:

```
printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: DIA \n");
scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[0].dia);
printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: MES \n");
scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[0].mes);
printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: ANIO \n");
scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[0].anio);
printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: DIA\n");
scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[1].dia);
printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: MES  \n");
scanf("%d", &a[i].fe[1].mes);
printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: ANIO \n");
```

Lo comentado sobre `scanf` es aplicable tamién para las variables propias de `a`:

```
scanf("%d",&a[i].legajo);
```

Y para la última instrucción del bucle:

```
scanf("%c",&rta);
```

¿Por qué no es necesario poner `&` en el caso de las llamadas a `gets`?

Porque el tipo `char[]` es implícitamente un puntero, luego a `gets` ya le estás pasando un puntero.

Y una última cosa:

```
struct alumnos
{
   int legajo [10];
};
```

La variable `legajo` tiene toda la pinta de no ser un arreglo, luego debería lucir así:

```
struct alumnos
{
   int legajo;
};
```

Y, para rematar, todo apunta a que la variable `i` debería ser sustituída por `c`. Actualmente usas `i` para realizar el conteo de registros añadios a la lista... pero la función debería devolver ese resultado en `c`. La variable `cont` podría desaparecer igualmente:

```
void carga_alu (struct alumnos a[ ], int *c)
{
  char rta='s';
  while (rta=='s')
  {
    printf("Ingrese el nombre y apellido del alumno \n");
    gets(a[*c].apnom);
    printf("Ingrese el legajo del alumno \n");
    scanf("%d",&a[*c].legajo);
    printf("Ingrese la direccion del alumno \n");
    gets(a[*c].direc);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: DIA \n");
    scanf("%d", &a[*c].fe[0].dia);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: MES \n");
    scanf("%d", &a[*c].fe[0].mes);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del alumno: ANIO \n");
    scanf("%d", &a[*c].fe[0].anio);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: DIA\n");
    scanf("%d", &a[*c].fe[1].dia);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: MES  \n");
    scanf("%d", &a[*c].fe[1].mes);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso a la institucion del alumno: ANIO \n");
    scanf("%d", &a[*c].fe[1].anio);
    *c++;
    printf("Desea cargar otro alumno? S o N");
    scanf("%c",&rta);
  }
}
```

Eso sí, ahora es de importancia crítica que inicialices la variable `cantalum`:

```
int main()
{
  struct alumnos alum[100];
  int cantalum = 0;

  carga_alu(alum,&cantalum);
```

Comment: Ahi arregle los errore que me marcaste!! pero me sigue sin funcionar cuando quiero ingresar datos en las estructuras anidadas @eferion

Comment: @MacaIgoillo estaba editando la pregunta...

Comment: Muchas gracias!! @eferion

Comment: @MacaIgoillo Te recomiendo echar un vistazo al [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ya que explica cómo funciona a grandes rasgos este portal. Y, por favor, si la respuesta te ha solucionado el problema márcala con el tick verde. Para mejorar el portal necesitamos incrementar el número de preguntas solucionadas.